# window.location.reload(); not working in a Google Apps Script web application. Not refreshing but blank page. (Chrome and Firefox; IE is working)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm building a web application using Google Apps Script. The HTML is mostly `<input>` and `<select>`, so after passing the values from inputs to a Google Spreadsheet, I want to refresh the page in order to get all the spaces in blank again for the next registration...

I'm calling this function using a `<button>`:

```
    function refreshPage(){
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I just get a blank page. All the screen is erased...
I have tried several ways and nothing is working... This problem is just happening in Chrome and Firefox, IE is working...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload a Google Apps Script web app with a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475342/how-to-reload-a-google-apps-script-web-app-with-a-link)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't stop Google Apps Script from masking redirected URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685553/cant-stop-google-apps-script-from-masking-redirected-url)

Answer (score 0):

try

window.open('url', '_top')

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)